# Two Errors in WxWidgets application

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to create a VNC client. Right now, I am creating the GUI that will be viewing the remote user's screen. Here is my code so far, I am using wxWidgets 3.2.2:

```cpp
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/socket.h>
#include <iostream>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);

    void OnConnect(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnSocketEvent(wxSocketEvent& event);

private:
    wxSocketServer m_server;
    wxSocketBase* m_clientSocket;
    bool m_connectionReceived;

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

enum
{
    ID_CONNECT = 1,
    ID_EXIT
};

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_MENU(ID_CONNECT, MyFrame::OnConnect)
EVT_MENU(ID_EXIT, MyFrame::OnExit)
EVT_SOCKET(wxID_ANY, MyFrame::OnSocketEvent)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame("wxWidgets Network App", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(800, 600));
    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size),
    m_server(), // Initialize without specifying flags
    m_clientSocket(nullptr),
    m_connectionReceived(false)
{
    // Create a menu
    wxMenu* menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_CONNECT, "Connect", "Connect to the client");
    menuFile->Append(ID_EXIT, "Exit", "Exit the application");

    wxMenuBar* menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "File");

    SetMenuBar(menuBar);

    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Waiting for a connection...");

    if (!m_server.Ok()) {
        wxLogError("Failed to set up the server.");
    }

    if (!m_server.WaitForAccept(wxSOCKET_WAITALL, -1)) {
        wxLogError("Failed to wait for incoming connections.");
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnConnect(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    if (!m_connectionReceived) {
        if (m_clientSocket) {
            m_connectionReceived = true;
            SetStatusText("Connection received.");
            SetTitle("CONNECTION RECEIVED");
        }
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::OnSocketEvent(wxSocketEvent& event)
{
    if (event.GetSocket() == &m_server) {
        if (event.GetSocketEvent() == wxSOCKET_CONNECTION) {
            m_clientSocket = m_server.Accept();
            if (m_clientSocket) {
                m_connectionReceived = true;
                SetStatusText("Connection received.");
                SetTitle("CONNECTION RECEIVED");
            }
        }
    }
}

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "wxSocketServer::wxSocketServer" matches the argument list   VNC_GUI_MAIN    C:\Users\User\source\repos\VNC_GUI_MAIN\main.cpp    50  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2512   'wxSocketServer::wxSocketServer': no appropriate default constructor available  VNC_GUI_MAIN    C:\Users\User\source\repos\VNC_GUI_MAIN\main.cpp    50
```

Updated my code, now running into this problem:

```cpp
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/socket.h>
#include <iostream>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);

    void OnConnect(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnSocketEvent(wxSocketEvent& event);

private:
    wxSocketServer m_server;
    wxSocketBase* m_clientSocket;
    bool m_connectionReceived;

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

enum
{
    ID_CONNECT = 1,
    ID_EXIT
};

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_MENU(ID_CONNECT, MyFrame::OnConnect)
EVT_MENU(ID_EXIT, MyFrame::OnExit)
EVT_SOCKET(wxID_ANY, MyFrame::OnSocketEvent)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame("wxWidgets Network App", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(800, 600));
    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size),
    m_server(nullptr),
    m_clientSocket(nullptr),
    m_connectionReceived(false)

{
    wxIPV4address addr;

    addr.AnyAddress();  // listen on all adapters

    unsigned short localListenPort = 64000; // listen on port 64000
    addr.Service(localListenPort);

    m_server = new wxSocketServer(localListenPort);
    // Create a menu
    wxMenu* menuFile = new wxMenu;
    menuFile->Append(ID_CONNECT, "Connect", "Connect to the client");
    menuFile->Append(ID_EXIT, "Exit", "Exit the application");

    wxMenuBar* menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append(menuFile, "File");

    SetMenuBar(menuBar);

    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText("Waiting for a connection...");

    if (!m_server.Ok()) {
        wxLogError("Failed to set up the server.");
    }

    if (!m_server.WaitForAccept(wxSOCKET_WAITALL, -1)) {
        wxLogError("Failed to wait for incoming connections.");
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnConnect(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    if (!m_connectionReceived) {
        if (m_clientSocket) {
            m_connectionReceived = true;
            SetStatusText("Connection received.");
            SetTitle("CONNECTION RECEIVED");
        }
    }
}

void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::OnSocketEvent(wxSocketEvent& event)
{
    if (event.GetSocket() == &m_server) {
        if (event.GetSocketEvent() == wxSOCKET_CONNECTION) {
            m_clientSocket = m_server.Accept();
            if (m_clientSocket) {
                m_connectionReceived = true;
                SetStatusText("Connection received.");
                SetTitle("CONNECTION RECEIVED");
            }
        }
    }
}

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

These are the errors I am now getting:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "wxSocketServer::wxSocketServer" matches the argument list   VNC_GUI_MAIN    C:\Users\User\source\repos\VNC_GUI_MAIN\main.cpp    50  


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0349   no operator "=" matches these operands  VNC_GUI_MAIN    C:\Users\User\source\repos\VNC_GUI_MAIN\main.cpp    62  


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "wxSocketServer::wxSocketServer" matches the argument list   VNC_GUI_MAIN    C:\Users\User\source\repos\VNC_GUI_MAIN\main.cpp    62  


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2665   'wxSocketServer::wxSocketServer': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types   VNC_GUI_MAIN    C:\Users\User\source\repos\VNC_GUI_MAIN\main.cpp    50  


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2665   'wxSocketServer::wxSocketServer': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types   VNC_GUI_MAIN    C:\Users\User\source\repos\VNC_GUI_MAIN\main.cpp    62  


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'wxSocketServer *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    VNC_GUI_MAIN    C:\Users\User\source\repos\VNC_GUI_MAIN\main.cpp    62
```

Comment: That is not a error message. Please post a complete error message from the Build panel.

Comment: Can we re-open. I was about to answer the question?

Comment: `Initialize without specifying flags` What about the first parameter address? A complete error message would contain an answer.

Comment: @MarianneSanders, please check the socket (server) sample.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a hint to what's wrong?  What port is your server listening on?  Where in the code is that specified?

You are initializing wxSocketServer like this:

```
m_server(), // Initialize without specifying flags
```

A quick internet search reveals it has this as a constructor:

```
wxSocketServer (const wxSockAddress &address, wxSocketFlags flags=wxSOCKET_NONE)
```

So you got to specify a listening address that includes a port.

Maybe this is what you want:

- Declare m_server as a pointer
- Initialize it manually in your constructor like this:

```
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
    : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size),
    m_server(nullptr),
    m_clientSocket(nullptr),
    m_connectionReceived(false)
{
    wxIPV4address addr;

    addr.AnyAddress();  // listen on all adapters

    unsigned short localListenPort = 64000; // listen on port 64000
    addr.Service(localListenPort);

    m_server = new wxSocketServer(localListenPort);
```

I think the bigger question is why you need to construct a server object when your stated purpose is to make a VNC client.  Unless the VNC protocol requires clients to accept connections back, this might not be needed.

Comment: `Declare m_server as a pointer` is a very bad advice after C++98. Neither pointer nor `addr` variable are necessary.

Comment: `wxIPV4address::Server` doesn't exist.

Comment: @273K - I meant "Service".

Comment: I am programming the GUI right now, I want the GUI to constantly be looking to a web server for the data being sent by the computer transmitting it's screen, and I need to be able to send data about key input to the computer I am connecting to so that I can control it. Do I not need to create a server object to do this?

Comment: *I want the GUI to constantly be looking* -- Admittedly, I have never used Qt, but the GUI shouldn't be doing business logic except to retrieve input and display output.  If you are programming key business logic inside a GUI component, what happens if you decide to change the GUI?  Do you now have to change the business logic?

Comment: I am getting this error now:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0289 no instance of constructor "wxSocketServer::wxSocketServer" matches the argument list VNC_GUI_MAIN C:\Users\User\source\repos\VNC_GUI_MAIN\main.cpp 62

Comment: I just updated my post, with the new errors I received after implementing your code @selbie

Comment: @MarianneSanders, polling the server is really bad idea. Please check the socket samples provided by wxWidgets for the details on how to properly implement it.